# Accessing a folder that I can't "name" in the shell

Tags: directory, encoding, find

I have a stubborn folder that someone must have created accidentally and that has persisted all this time. I can see it with:

```
# find /var/www/html -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

which gives me:

```
/var/www/html
/var/www/html/files
/var/www/html/.?
```

unfortunately the question mark there is **not** the actual character `?`, it merely seems to denote that there is no proper glyph and/or translation for that character. So something like `rmdir` is out of the question. My system has UTF-8 as the default locale as so many modern Ubuntu systems, but admittedly the folder in question may have originated on a RHEL or CentOS box (`tar`ed up and unpacked).

```
# env|grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

When trying to `cd .\?` (as mentioned before it is not actually `?`) I get auto-corrected to `.` by bash and actually end up in `/var/www/html/.` for some reason. Now if I can't "name" this folder usefully, I cannot access it in any way. How can I get rid of it without putting the whole system in jeopardy?

Now I installed `detox` already but that only seems to act on files, not folders, according to its documentation and besides it still requires that I be able to name the object somehow to do something with it.

Comment: If you change directories to `/var/www/html` and type `ls -al`do any hidden directories show up starting with a `.`?  Like `.cache` or `.config` or someting with a `.` in front

Comment: `rm -i` makes `rm` prompt for confirmation of any file. Just press `n` for all but that one.

Comment: @ScottStookey: the folder in question shows up as `.?` just like before. Observe: `drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 2007-09-03 10:08 .?`

Comment: @Rinzwind: spot on. Thanks so much. Could you please write this up as an answer? Did `# rm -ir *` then got asked: `rm: remove directory `.\n'?` which I responded to with a `y` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions, first try using tab completion

```
cd /var/www
```

rm -rf ./.<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

Or use find

```
cd /var/www
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -ri '{}' \;
```

If that fails, try running fsck (from a live CD).

Post any error messages or odd behavior you get

Comment: sorry, the first one wouldn't work either way because it uses the same mechanisms I mentioned before `rm -rf ./.<TAB><TAB>` gives me `./  ../` as options. The second would also remove all other other subfolders.

Comment: the second one does not remove all other subfolders. the `i` in `rm -rfi` will invoke a `yes`/`no` question before deleting ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind: got you, because of the `i` in there ... so he was slightly earlier then. Will accept this answer then.

Answer (score 2):

`rm -i *` makes `rm` prompt for confirmation of any file. Just press `n` for all but that one and press `y` for the one you want removed.

You can also guess the amount of chars with `rm -i .???` for 3 chars (so you do not risc pressing `y` once too many).

Comment: Thanks. Also thanks for pointing out my misconception about the other answer :)

Comment: you are welcome! just keep bodhi.zazen's answer. It's a bit longer than needed as you can see but it's a good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only this two directories

```
/var/www/html/files
/var/www/html/.?
```

under `/var/www/html/`, you can remove the one not named `files` with the command

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name files -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Hehe, I am aware of this ugly workaround, but I think the question itself is interesting, because in many cases you may not have a single folder in there ...